# Maven clean install jbossweb dependency unauthorized

Tags: java, maven, jboss-web

On my project, i try to install it for the first time. But when i launch clean install, it can't download the dependency "jbossweb" because of unauthorized.

On mvnrepository( https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.web/jbossweb/7.4.10.Final) , it says this artifact is located at Spring Plugins repository (https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/).

That is what I have in my pom.xml :

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>securecentral</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

And it define this dependency like this :

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.web</groupId>
                <artifactId>jbossweb</artifactId>
                <version>7.4.10.Final</version>
            </dependency>
```

The error when I launch clean install :

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Pilotage_WS: Could not
> resolve dependencies for project bpce:Pilotage_WS:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
> Failed to collect dependencies at
> org.jboss.web:jbossweb:jar:7.4.10.Final: Failed to read artifact
> descriptor for org.jboss.web:jbossweb:jar:7.4.10.Final: Could not
> transfer artifact org.jboss.web:jbossweb:pom:7.4.10.Final from/to
> spring (https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/): authentication
> failed for
> https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/jboss/web/jbossweb/7.4.10.Final/jbossweb-7.4.10.Final.pom,
> status: 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]

I don't understand, we need authentication ? If yes i couldn't find any information about this.
Moreover, when I go on https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/, it redirects to https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/plugins-release/, but i cannot find the dependency here anyway.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with JBoss repository:

```
<repositories>
    ...
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-releases</id>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```